C Program ending after printf()
I'm making a mini system for personal educational purposes, but I'm not having success in this part.
After executing a printf(), the program simply returns:

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

const char* nomePastaContas = "contas";
char *ibanPessoal;
char *passwordPessoal;

void loginMenu(){

    system("cls");

    printf("\n\n IBAN: ");

    scanf("%s", &ibanPessoal);

    printf("\n\n Password: ");

    scanf("%s", &passwordPessoal);
    printf("Debug");
    verificarConta(ibanPessoal, passwordPessoal);

}

void verificarConta(char* iban, char* pswd){
    // Verificar o Login OU criar conta.
    printf("Debug 2");
    char* pastaDoUsuario = "nil";
    printf("Debug 3");
    printf("\n\n IBAN %s\n PASSWORD: %s", iban, pswd); // the program stops here... All debugs are fine, but debug4 isnt showing.
    printf("Debug 4");
    printf("\n\n%s", pastaDoUsuario);
    sprintf(pastaDoUsuario, "contas/%s", iban);
    printf("\n\n Pasta de Usuario: %s", pastaDoUsuario);
    if(_access(pastaDoUsuario, 0) == 0){
            printf("Usuario encontrado");
    }
    else{
        printf("Usuario nao encontrado.");
    }
    Sleep(100000);

}

Objective: Continue the program after the printf() that does not work.

Something like char *ibanPessoal; just declares a pointer - no memory is allocated for it - you need to do that.

If we're to tell you why the process is returning the code it does, we probably need to see main. Also, which printf is it failing after? (I can tell you right now that the printf is not the issue (although a later one might be). If you see the output, the problem is something that happens after it's printed.)

scanf("%s", &passwordPessoal); and the other look suspicious. If passwordPessoal is a string, it doesn't need the & and if it is a pointer, it's an error. So either way it's wrong. Also, you have no protection against buffer overflow.

Error 0xC0000005 is a memory access violation. This incomplete program isn't enough to be exact. Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

scanf("%s", &ibanPessoal); has three faults: 1. It should be scanf("%s", ibanPessoal);, 2. ibanPessoal doesn't point to memory where scanf can write. 3. %s should never be used without limiting how many chars scanf is allowed to write to the buffer

On Windows, error 0xC0000005 is an Access Violation, which means you tried to access invalid memory.
The problem is here:
char *ibanPessoal;
char *passwordPessoal;
...
scanf("%s", &ibanPessoal);
...
scanf("%s", &passwordPessoal);
...

ibanPessoal and passwordPessoal are pointers, but you are not setting them to point at any valid memory.  scanf() will not allocate memory, only write to existing memory.
Worse, you are telling scanf() to write the input data to the memory addresses where the variables themselves reside, not to the memory addresses where they are pointing at (if they were pointing at valid memory).
You need to allocate memory for scanf() to write to. Try this instead:
char ibanPessoal[256];
char passwordPessoal[256];

void loginMenu(){

    system("cls");

    printf("\n\n IBAN: ");
    scanf("%255s", ibanPessoal);

    printf("\n\n Password: ");
    scanf("%255s", passwordPessoal);

    printf("Debug");
    verificarConta(ibanPessoal, passwordPessoal);
}

